# I need help receiving the data from an api every min (looping it)

Tags: python, hypixel-api

***Im trying to loop the part fetching the reference from the api, there really isn't an error but i couldn't find the correct way to loop it and needed help***

pastebin: https://paste-bin.xyz/46617 (sorry couldn't paste the code here idk why)

I just need help looping the part fetching info and i want it to have the value of gameType and Mode form the api every x seconds

Comment: you cannot paste code here becuase too long? so try shorten it by yourself, removing the unnecessary part(unrelated to the problem)

Comment: you might have an XY problem; polling is an inefficient solution...

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that?